# Incorrect number of subscripts on matrix. while assigning values from dataframe to matrix

Tags: r

Error message pops up when assigning values in dataframe A to matrix B.

A is a dataframe contains 9000 observations of 3 variables. Data are simulated values of 1000 iterations. Each iteration contains 9 values, i.e. 9 * 1000 = 9000. 
V1 is iteration ID, variable name(which not useful for now), V3 is the variable I need.

I create a matrix B to keep values from A[,3]. However, the first value in each iteration will be discarded. Therefore, only 8 values in each iter are kept.

```
B <- matrix(NA, nrow = 1000, ncol = 8)
for(i in 1:iter){
  for(m in 1:8){
    B[i,m] <- A[9*(i-1)+m+1,3]
  }
}
```

Then I got the error message. Couldn't figure it out anyways. Any help or suggestions or idea are the most welcome!

Comment: To add another point, I got rid of the error message by transforming B from matrix to dataframe by _ B <- as.data.frame(B)_. I don't understand why but this seems a viable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand well, you basically want to fill the matrix row by row with all values of `A[,3]` except the first value of each group of 9 values.

Instead of using two `for` loops, you can go straight by filling directly the matrix with `A[,3]` when creating the matrix object `B`. It will fill it column by column, so you just have to transpose the matrix and remove the first column to get your result. The code looks like this:

```r
B <- t(matrix(A$V3, nrow = 9, ncol = 1000))
B <- B[,-1]
```

**Example**
We defined a dataframe A with 3 variables and 9000 observations

```r
A = data.frame(V1 = rnorm(9000),
               V2 = rnorm(9000),
               V3 = rnorm(9000))
```

```r
> head(A)
          V1          V2          V3
1  1.0755625  2.82414180  1.76860717
2  0.3421535  0.85857695  0.05682035
3  1.3747495 -0.01151905  0.90259357
4  1.1589849  0.91009114  0.35132258
5 -0.1107268  1.38244412  0.76163226
6 -1.5551836  1.27199029 -0.56923898
```

Then we apply the code below to generate B and we can check that B is:

```r
> head(B[,1:5])
            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,]  0.05682035  0.9025936  0.35132258  0.7616323 -0.5692390
[2,] -0.75018285 -0.6160903 -1.43556979 -0.3983150  2.0722279
[3,]  0.97226064  1.5366989  0.06546405 -0.5666010  2.3127568
[4,] -0.66904980 -1.9877136 -0.49963116  0.9217295 -0.6338961
[5,]  0.42339924 -0.6077871  0.16467356 -0.3301223 -0.6031495
[6,]  0.82212429  0.3383385 -0.26872905  1.1513397 -0.2644223
```

You can notice that first row of B correspond to first values of A WITHOUT the first one. and if we check dimensions of B, you will see:

```r
> dim(B)
[1] 1000    8
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear: I don't want all values in A[,3]. The 1st value in every 9 rows will be dropped. That's why I have 9*1000=9000 rows in A while 8*1000 =8000 cells in B.

Comment: @JOJO67373,  I clarified my answer. In my code we are dropping the first column of B (after transposition), so you get the right format for B. Try the example or with your real data and you will see if it works